# Матч группы в Ruby

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

имеем строку:
*\r\n\t\t\t\t$6.32Save $1.33 instantly\r\n*
следующее регулярное выражение: **([\d.,]+)** возвращает только первые цифры (6.32), кто нибудь может ответить почему так происходит? По идее он должен вернуть обе цифры

Comment: Почему он должен вернуть две группы? На данном образце текста выражение соответствует ровно тому, что возвращает.   
В цикле делайте последовательный перебор, как например в java:  

    while (matcher.match()){
        ... работа с совпадением
    }
Либо, если есть аналог preg_match_all из php- используйте его.  
P.S. Я не силен в руби, но так как долго никто не отвечает даю общие советы.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не понятно, вы хотите получить на выходе `6.32` и `1.33` или что?
Тогда вам нужно делать так, и никакие группы не нужны:

```
"\r\n\t\t\t\t$6.32Save $1.33 instantly\r\n".scan /\d+\.\d+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
"\r\n\t\t\t\t$6.32Save $1.33 instantly\r\n".scan /([\d.,]+)/
 => [["6.32"], ["1.33"]]
```

Я только что проверил его в `irb` - ваше регулярное выражение `([\d.,]+)` нормально возвращает оба числа.